# How can I write a list without duplicate with only for, if and boolean

Tags: python, python-2.7

My professor gave me an exercise where I write a function that returns a list without the duplicate to the old list.
This is the code but I don't know how to write the method without using `.remove()`:

```
def distinct(lst):
    lstnew = []
    c = range(len(lst))
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        if i in range(len(lst)) != c:
            lstnew += [i]
            c += 1
            return lstnew

print distinct([1,3,1,2,6])
print distinct([['a','ab','a','ab']])
```

I forgot to write an important thing, I must preserve order in the output list.

[UPDATE]
After I read the answer of Jai Srivastav I code this:

```
def distinct(lst):
lstnew = []
for element in lst:
    if element not in lstnew:
        lstnew = lstnew + [element]
return lstnew
```

And It works perfectly

Comment: You aren't using `remove` now.

Comment: What do you want the output to be for those two examples, just `[1,3,2,6]` and `['a','ab']` -- does the output list need to maintain the order of the input list?

Comment: Does performance matter? Many implementations (ones which do an O(n) list traversal to determine if something exists) will be very slow, such that you wouldn't want to use them in real life.

Comment: check the indentation of your `return` statement and think about when that'll get executed

Comment: Something that none of the answers (currently) address is your second call to `distinct` where you have a list of a list.  How do you want *that* to be handled?

Comment: I can't use remove, the output list need to maintain the input list and the indentation how can help me???

Comment: You used + operator for the concatenation because you have some limits set by your professor (it's fine), but keep in mind that if you code a program yourself, the append method is recommended.

Comment: Of course, if I code a program without limitation I'll use all method for the lists!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def distinct(lst):
    dlst = []
    for val in lst:
        if val not in dlst:
            dlst.append(val)
    return dlst
```

Comment: sorry but I can't use append

Answer (score 2):

Is this considered cheating?

```
>>> distinct = lambda lst: list(set(lst))
>>> distinct([1,3,1,2,6])
[1, 2, 3, 6]
>>> distinct(['a','ab','a','ab'])
['a', 'ab']
```

Answer (score 1):

If order isn't important, you can cast it to a `set`, then back to a `list`

```
def distinct(lst):
    return list(set(lst))
```

Comment: Just note, this will not preserve input ordering.

Comment: @jedwards As noted in the first line of the answer -  `"If order isn't important"`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to eliminate duplicates AND preserve order you can do this:

```
def distinct(lst):
    seen = set()
    for item in lst:
        if item not in seen:
            yield item
            seen.add(item)
```

---

```
a = [1,3,1,2,6]

print(list(distinct(a)))

[1,3,2,6]
```

---

```
b = ['a','ab','a','ab']

print(list(distinct(b)))

['a', 'ab']
```

See a demo here: https://ideone.com/a2khCg

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use the method for the lists

Comment: Oh I see. This is a limitation of the exercise, but in real life it would have been good :) If I'll think about another solution I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are Excellent Solutions That I Already Applied. But my professor said us that we don't must use the methods of the list. Has anyone else got any more thoughts?